# filter combobox content in kendo column

Tags: javascript, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can the content of combobox be filtered? I would need to filter only items that contain "AB" in their name, I tried to do it with some of kendo operators but didn't get any result. Here is the code of my combobox editor:

```
  $('<select kendo-combo-box k-min-length="1" k-data-text-field="\'UnitGlobalName\'" k-data-value-field="\'_Key\'" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" k-data-source="dataSourceKendoOdsUnits(undefined)" />').appendTo(container);
```